# Kedusha during relations

Tags: sexuality, kedusha-holiness

I have heard that the highest potential for kedusha and the highest potential to experience or perceive yichud Hashem is during relations.

1- Is there a source for this idea?

2- Assuming that this is true, what is the explanation behind the idea?

Comment: what do you mean by yichud Hashem

Comment: @ray I'll go with the broadest definition I know of: The 'oneness' of God (everything spoken of in Derech Hashem by the Ramchal in Chapter 1) despite the fact or in relationship to the apparent non-oneness that we perceive.

Comment: I am far far far from a Kabbalah student, so I'm quite unsure of exact source locations, but I believe that concept is in the Zohar somewhere, where having relations on earth was supposed to symbolize/imitate the "oneness" of God by the joining of His "male" and "female" aspects, with each partner concentrating on the respective attributes during..I remember reading a translation of part of it that had the sensitive parts in Latin...I'm sure there are Kabbalah students here that can source and explain it better than me...

Comment: This sounds similar to a statement in a forged letter ascribed to the rambam insulting French scholars who (IIRC) only think about God while eating and having relations.